# Difference between sass-rails helpers "image_url" and "asset_url" in rails 4.0?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have a jpg in my /app/assets/images directory and am using it as a background with the following CSS.

```
body {
  background-image: image_url('metal_texture.jpg')
}
```

The asset_url helper also works in this case. Since the Rails 4 asset pipeline doesn't care which directory in /app/assets that the file is placed, is there a reason to use image_url vs asset_url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source code: [**image_url**](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/863c488bb05de3b38a81fa37349977adc0db59e3/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L287), [**asset_url**](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/863c488bb05de3b38a81fa37349977adc0db59e3/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L151)

`image_url` actually calls `asset_url` passing one specific option: `{type: :image}`
And **[compute_asset_path](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/863c488bb05de3b38a81fa37349977adc0db59e3/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L182)** finds asset directory based on that `option[:type]`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no difference between `image-url` and `asset-url` (underscored in Ruby, hyphenated in Sass).

`image-url` calls `asset-url` method specifying `{type: image}`

You can use the `asset-url` when you don't know the kind of asset.